# I changed DNS server to those of Google, but now CS 1.6 ping has risen to 300

Tags: dns, ping

I had the default DNS lookup settings. I used to play Counter Strike 1.6 online and my ping was 40-50. However I noticed that I could not access other sites and an error appears like "DNS lookup failed". After some weeks even this stackoverflow.com site did not open and had the same error. So I tried to figure out the solution and changed DNS servers to those of Google (something like 8.8.4.4). Now all the sites are accessible and I do not encounter the DNS lookup failed error. However, now when I play Counter Strike 1.6 online, my ping is 250-300 due to which my gameplay lags a lot. Please help me out. I want Counter Strike 1.6 to work with the earlier normal ping and also those DNS lookup error do not appear again. (Note: I have not changed my computer system including hardware and software, neither changed my browser, neither changed Counter Strike 1.6 version, neither changed my ISP and Internet Speed. Also my Internet Speed is 2 Mbps from start).
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CS servers are likely using the IP address where the DNS request comes from to return the closest server to the sending IP address. So you end up using their server that's "closest" to Google's DNS server.

Contact your Internet provider, see if there's a DNS server you can use that will work for you.

Comment: Just one more doubt. If i connect a CS server that is close to Google's DNS server than would that have a low ping?

Comment: Not necessarily. It would have a low ping to Google, but that won't necessarily help you.